# SQL - JOIN vs IN performance WHEN the IN is an actual list of values (instead of a query)

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql

I've seen questions fairly similar to this one, but they don't exactly cover what I want. Let's say we have a table full of data about Stores:

```
Stores
(
     Store int,
     Address string,
     ... (20+ columns of data),
     ,PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Store)
)
```

Now let's say this table has hundreds of millions of rows. I want information about 100 of these stores spread throughout the table. I have another table with these 100 Stores:

```
MyStores
(
     Store int,
     PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Store)
)
```

I want to know the performance difference between these two statements:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Stores a
JOIN MyStores b
     ON a.Store = b.Store
```

vs.

```
    SELECT *
    FROM Stores
    WHERE Store IN (12, 34, 56, ..., 99999)

 -- 100 stores in this list
```

This is not using dynamic SQL, and I already have the MyStores table, so no need to worry about that setup time. Just want to compare the actual processing speeds and/or query plans for the two statements above. I would think the second would be naturally faster, but if the list is very long, I'm wondering if it ends up being slower. Any thoughts? Bonus points for links to answers!

Also, if you think the answer changes when we JOIN more tables (for other columns), as compared to adding more IN lists with an AND, then feel free to extend the analysis.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is that you need to try it out:  your data, your system.

In general, I would expect the two to have comparable execution performance.  For the fixed list, SQL Server should be doing index lookups.

The optimizer should be smart enough to do the same thing with the secondary table.

Of course, as the "list" gets larger, SQL Server is balancing the overhead of redirecting through an index to just reading the table and comparing the values.  So, the performance and plans should always be checked.